# Conditional Formatting with two or more conditions in same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight multiple rows in a table based on multiple values in one column. For example if the column was a list of colors, I want to highlight all rows with the colors Blue, Green or Red in Column D. I tried Conditional Formatting with the rule:

```
=IF(OR($D1=”Blue”,$D1="Green",$D1="Red"))
```

but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. First of all, you don’t need the `IF`, the conditional format is ‘triggered’ by a TRUE response to the Rule (though it does no harm!`*`) However I think your formula should work provided it is applied to the correct range (go to Manage Rules and check what **Applies to** is set to) and what you want is the same format for all of “Blue”, “Green” and “Red”.

If you want blue highlighting for Blue, green highlighting for Green etc (or similar) the simplest way may be to use an icon set or perhaps three separate rules (=D1="Blue", =D1="Green" etc) that can be applied in any order.

`*` Provided using the correct syntax - say as:

```
=IF(OR($D1="Blue",$D1="Green",$D1="Red"),TRUE,)
```

(note also no smart quotes).

```
=OR($D1="Blue",$D1="Green",$D1="Red")
```

should however be adequate.